# Link inside a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a link inside a label in a ListView item template but I can't make it work.

I have this label:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="SummaryLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Summary").ToString().Substring(0,Math.Min(200,Eval("Summary").ToString().Length)) + "... " + "More"%>'/>
```

and I want the word More at the end to be a link to the details page of the item. Tried putting "More" inside an anchor tag and hyperlink but I get badly formed tags. I'd appreciate any help to solving this or suggestions on alternative approaches.

Comment: I would do that as two separate controls - a `Label` and a `HyperLink`.

Comment: Why not make this 2 controls (a label and a hyperlink) instead of one?

Comment: @DStanley Tried using 2 controls but my design gets messed up. I need the link to be exactly after the last letter in the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want as follows:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="SummaryLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Summary").ToString().Substring(0,Math.Min(200,Eval("Summary").ToString().Length)) + "... " + @"<a href=""Oherpage.aspx"">More</a>"%>'/>
```

Note how the `<a>` is constructed in there... `OtherPage.aspx` would be your link to whatever other page you need to send the user to.

Comment: I got a couple of questions. Are the double quotation marks necessary? And what is the @ used for? Btw I get a compiler error... A ) is missing....

Comment: Probably coz I changed Oherpage.aspx with Details.aspx?ID=Eval("Id")

Comment: Read this for a thorough explanation of string literals in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx / but yes, the double quotation marks are necessary when preceded by the @ sign.

Comment: I use this technique quite a bit to point to an HTTP Handler that generates PDFs that stream back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, revising, have you done this?

```
   <asp:Label ...><Asp:HyperLink ...>More...</HyperLink> </Label>
```

Comment: I think it's because he doesn't want the text in the label to be part of the link, which is a reasonable thing to do...

Comment: As Icarus mentioned I just want the word More to be the link not the whole label text

Comment: There it would be just for it. You just have to add the value of the label and then add the link as provided above, either by setting the text attribute or placing it before the hyperlink tags.

Either way it would be the same.

Comment: @JoseGomez that's the problem, you can't do that markup in asp.net. It won't render the link.

Comment: @JoseGomez For some reason the Hyperlink doesn't work at all like that. Here is the resulting code http://jsfiddle.net/A2uec/2/ It's not even there....